# C++14: Does the standard allow subtracting a delta from std::end()?

Tags: c++11, iterator, std

The question is pretty self explanatory I think.

If I have a `std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3}`, are `v.end() - 1` or `v.end()--` valid expressions?

I know that most iterators support it, but the question is, is it defined behavior? Unfortunately it is really hard to find information about it. Isn't there an iterator specification? The standard itself seems to be very vague about it or I just missed the passage that defines them on such a low level.

For example look at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/end/

*"It does not point to any element, and thus shall not be dereferenced."*
std::end() is obviously something less general than (v.begin() + 1), which is the most general one and supports all operations. So this begs the question, which operations are defined behavior for std::end() and std::begin() respectively.

I need this for writing my own library. Some more advanced lazy evaluation iterators are very difficult to write under the light of `v.end()--` being a valid expression, since the "end" is not really known without iterating through it or tracking the "end" within the iterator itself which makes the whole a LOT more complex, since you need to special case almost everything inside the iterator implementation.

The fact that `v.end()--` causes such headaches for me made me wonder if it is even allowed ;). Unfortunately, the "end" must be extremely efficient due to frequent usage patterns, so it must be constant time, that's what makes things so difficult here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators are modelled after pointers.

Pointers into a range can take a value from pointing to the first element, to pointing to one-past-the-end element.  If you move a pointer outside of that range, undefined behavior occurs (immediately).

End is based off of the one-past-the-end pointer.  You cannot increase the end iterator and get defined behavior, and you cannot dereference it, but other than that it is just another iterator.

Eric's "ranges v3" proposal for C++1z includes asymmetric ranges, where the type of the begin iterator is different than the type of the end iterator.  This allows efficient "null terminated string" ranges, where you say "start at this location, continue until you hit the null at the end" that compiles down to the equivalent of hand-written C code iteration.

Finding evidence that this is true is tricky, because you are asking for evidence of absence: any part of the C++ standard could include the text "if you decrement the end iterator of a vector, the result is undefined", and if I quoted the entire rest of the standard except that sentence, it would still be undefined if you did `v.end()--`.  However, there are examples, such as Table 101, where decrementing a copy of the end iterator is used.  So either calling `back()` is undefined behavior, or a copy of the iterator returned by `end()` can be decremented.

See http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4431.pdf for a copy of the current draft standard.  The behavior of the end iterator of a vector has not changed with regards to your question in any material way.

Comment: `v.end()--` only works if the iterator isn't a pointer. The pesky built-in `--` requires an lvalue operand.

Comment: Also, Table 110 in [bidirectional.iterators] says that the only precondition of `--r` is that "there exists `s` such that `r == ++s`."

Comment: I like your answer ;). Give me some more time to process it fully. But generally the null termination issue is a simple model of the problem I have here. Let's assume you had those asymmetric ranges and wanted to do std::end()--, then, effectively, the iterator needs to scan for the null termination and give you back an iterator to the element before NULL. It's possible but not constant time and screws up the complexity guarantees you can give to users. This is exactly my problem, just that mine involves more complex data structures, but it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Also doing std::end()-- on a generating sequence would enter an infinite loop :D. As an extreme example. Which is why they should be forward iterable only.

Comment: Another cool thing about asymmetric ranges is that you can treat std::end() and "std::begin() + size" differently. In the latter case, you know where the NULL is in the string, because you actually iterated through it from beginning, so subtracting from end is constant time. But subtracting from std::end() can never be constant time in quite a variety of situations.

Comment: @thesaint the slower way to currently handle it is a flag saying "I am an end iterator".  Then `==` etc treats end iterators differently.  Advsncing may set the flag, or we could just rely on equivalence.  The name of the "end iterator" kind of type is "Sentinal".

Comment: I know. I am doing something similar. std::end() will tag an iterator as artificial end and then only functions that need the "true" end will call "sanitizeEnding()" which causes the iterator to fully resolve its ending by iterating through the collection... This saves performance in the use case (in contrast to your suggestion) and increases the overhead substantially in some corner cases.